# Is it possible to "polyfill" a vulnerable Flash player to a users machine when they visit a web page?

Tags: web-browser, browser-extensions

This is about the concept of adding "necessary code" to a webpage to ensure that any client can view the "content" provided through that page. This sort of code is sometimes referred to as a [polyfill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill_(programming)).

In this case though I am more concerned about merely JavaScript code or Flash content but an actual Flash player.

My question is about using the currently available methods to include a Flash player within the page itself. To accomplish this the web server would of course have to determine the client OS version and related details but this should be possible using common fingerprinting methods.

The scenario in which I am seeing this as a concern is if the embedded Flash player is vulnerable to some known attack vectors.

**Question:**

Is it possible to "polyfill" a Flash player (or other "media player") to a users machine when they visit a web page?

Comment: the server can't tell, you need to sniff around in client-side JS.